# How can I make sure 'this' refers to the object literal within the object literal?

Tags: javascript

Here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXTmm/).

I want to make sure `this` inside `obj` is `obj` so that I can call `a` from `b`. I'm using `obj` in a different function, and when I put a breakpoint inside `b`, I find that `this` is the window, not `obj`.

```
var obj = {
    a: function() { return 2 },
    b: function() { return 5+ this.a() },
}

$('#hey').text(obj.b());
```

`obj` is defined in a file used by many other classes, so it wouldn't make sense to define either of the methods at the site of using `obj`.

Judging from @Kamil's answer, it looks like I may need to pass in `a` as a parameter to `b`. As in:

```
var user = obj.b(obj.a);

var obj = {
  a: function() { return 2 },
  b: function(func) { return 5 + func() },
}
```

**EDIT** The following works, but it's messy. Is there a more elegant way?

I ended up changing

```
startingSMA = this.simple_moving_average(startingSMA, period, accessor)
```

to the following:

```
startingSMA = (function(startingSMA, period, accessor) {
                 return this.simple_moving_average(startingSMA, period, accessor)                  
              }).apply(Statistics, [startingSMA, period, accessor]);
```

Comment: this is only object not window when you use it in b ...

Comment: @PrasathK `this` refers to the global object in the op's code, which is indeed `window` in web browsers.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that. Your code is totally fine, also in the fiddle.

Comment: In your fiddle demo, it is refer to `obj`, how to reproduce it refer to `window`?

Comment: @Rose - Your original code works fine and as you intended. Please disregard my answer and any of my comments you might have seen.

Comment: It's unclear *why* your code is problematic. Your fiddle works fine. Please post code that is more obviously broken, since it's not possible to diagnose code that works. Whatever problem you are experiencing in your actual code, you have not reproduced it here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this hasn't been suggested yet - use `bind`:

```
var obj = {};
obj.b = (function () {
    // "this" will always be "obj"
}).bind(obj);
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `foo.bar()`, the `this` value will be set to `foo`. So I don't see any problem with your code.

However, when you call a method indirectly, as in

```
var qux = foo.bar;
qux(); // no dot-notation
```

the global object becomes `this`. Maybe this is what happens to you?

To force a certain `this`, use `call` or `apply`:

```
qux.call(foo);
qux.apply(foo);
```

Comment: There's no problem with her code only the second time you run it and the `obj` variable is already set.

Comment: @KamilSzot - what do you mean "only the second time"? There's nothing wrong with the OP's code or with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jquery 1.4 , you can use [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and choose easy a particular context:

```
$('#hey').text( $.proxy(obj.b, obj) );
```

In this case the first param is the function that you want to call, and the second param is the context.

Here is the [Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/YXTmm/1/)